# Convert Rails TimeZone for use in Javascript Day.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, dayjs

I'm using Rails TimeZone Input:

```
 <%= time_zone_select( "user", "time_zone", nil, default: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" ) %>
```

but now I'm trying to pass that value (stored in javascript in a variable called **user_timezone_string**) to a javascript component using day.js:

```
  dayjs.extend(utc)
  dayjs.extend(timezone)

  var now = dayjs().tz(user_timezone_string)
```

I've tried doing:

```
  <%= ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo(time_zone).to_s.sub! ' - ', '/' %>
```

which works for some timezones, but fails on Bueno Aires (GMT 03:00) and others.

Comment: What is the output in the console of user_timezone_string and of now?

Comment: According to its [documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/timezone), day.js returns the "timezone" as an IANA representative location, like "Europe/Berlin" which represents all [current and historic offsets for Berlin](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin), including all changes to local and daylight saving offsets. A timezone like "Pacific Time" (aka Pacific Standard Time or PST) represents a single offset, i.e. UTC-8. Currently all the places that are in the PST timezone are observing daylight saving, aka PDT.

Comment: PS. PST also stands for Pitcairn Standard Time, which doesn't observe daylight saving so is PST all year round. :-)